# How do I tell if my BLE communication use asymmetric encryption, if encrypted at all? (BLE 5.x)

Tags: encryption, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, encryption-symmetric, encryption-asymmetric

I want to know if my BLE 5 (low energy, not "typical"/core bluetooth) embedded system uses (preferably asymmetric) encryption, if encrypted at all.

I'm using this ble module that is communicating with an SOC. My SOC is capable of encryption but the FAE of the BLE module product couldn't come up with any useful information.

My program doesn't appear to have a bonding/pairing process, but I could be wrong since I did not take a closer look at the HAL layer program.

My question is, does BLE 5 require encryption?

If not, how do I find out if my connection is encrypted or not, using methods other than sniffers? For example are there any steps which must be gone through to facilitate encryption, in which case I should check if these steps were skipped or not? (If skipped then surely my communication is in plain texts).

ETA: The target BLE module is based on nrf52832, don't know what BLE stack/softdevice they are using. My soc is STM32WB55 series, using a rather comprehensive BLE stack that supports most functions of which name I couldn't recall for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

BLE does not require encryption for a connection to be made.

At first, every BLE connection starts in Security Mode 1, Level 1 which does not use any encryption at all. Every message will be sent in cleartext. To increase the security two devices have to "pair". Security keys are exchange during the pairing process. There are multiple different pairing methods with different requirements. Have a look at [this](https://medium.com/rtone-iot-security/deep-dive-into-bluetooth-le-security-d2301d640bfc) article for a starting point.

The pairing process is usually not started manually but automatically as soon as a device tries to access a secured characteristic. If you are using a phone to access such a characteristic you will be prompted with a pairing request popup. Based on your description I would assume that your connection is currently not encrypted.

To enable encryption on your SoC please have a look at the function `aci_gatt_add_char`. [This](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjt4cy9uIbtAhUSmRoKHa0aAuoQFjAAegQIBRAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.st.com%2Fresource%2Fen%2Fuser_manual%2Fdm00162667-the-bluenrgms-bluetooth-le-stack-application-command-interface-aci-stmicroelectronics.pdf&usg=AOvVaw09qujynzhC9TBZlVMKcpVU) document (direct download link) refers to this function on page 55 and shows that it takes `Security_Permissions` as an argument. The next page states the possible options as:

- `0x00`: ATTR_PERMISSION_NONE
- `0x01`: Need authentication to read
- `0x02`: Need authorization to read
- `0x04`: Link should be encrypted to read
- `0x08`: Need authentication to write
- `0x10`: Need authorization to write
- `0x20`: Link should be encrypted for write

Comment: "How to enable encryption for a characteristic depends on the peripheral you are using."   How should I comprehend that?

Comment: I don't know what SOC you are using or how you are programing it. Maybe you can add those informations to your question

Comment: Got it. Added. Please check the main question.

Comment: Thank you, I'm looking into it with your method, may provide updates in the future!